# TypeError: this.props.changeUser is not a function

Tags: reactjs

I am new in React Js and want to call the parent method from the child method.
There is a class login.jsx when someone clicks on submits button then a method changeUser in FirstPage.jsx should be invoked but when I try the online solution I am getting same error again and again that this.props.changeUser is not a function.

Login.jsx (child class)

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
class Login extends Component {
    constructor(props){
        super(props);
        this.state ={
            user : null
        }
        this.onNameChange = this.onNameChange.bind(this);
        this.onHandleClick = this.onHandleClick.bind(this);
    }
    onNameChange = (event)=>{
       this.setState({
           user:event.target.value
       })
    }
    onHandleClick=(event)=>{
       event.preventDefault();
       this.props.changeUser("hello");
    }
    render() {  
        return (
            <form>
            <h3>Sign In</h3>
            <div>
                <label>User Name</label>
                <input type="text" name="userId" placeholder="Enter User name" onChange ={this.onNameChange}/>
            </div>
            <button className="btn btn-primary btn-block" onClick={this.onHandleClick}>Submit</button>
        </form>
        );
    }
}

export default Login;
```

FirstPage.jsx (parent class)

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import Login from './Login';

class Firstpage extends Component {
    constructor(props){
        super(props);
        this.state=
        {
            user:null
        }
        this.changeUser = this.changeUser.bind(this)
    }
    changeUser =(x)=>{
        console.log(x)
    }
    render() {
        return (
            <div>
               <Login changeUser ={this.changeUser}/>
            </div>
        );
    }
}

export default Firstpage;import React, { Component } from 'react';
import Login from './Login';

class Firstpage extends Component {
    constructor(props){
        super(props);
        this.state=
        {
            user:null
        }
        this.changeUser = this.changeUser.bind(this)
    }
    changeUser =(x)=>{
        console.log(x)
    }
    render() {
        return (
            <div>
               <Login changeUser ={this.changeUser}/>
            </div>
        );
    }
}

export default Firstpage;
```

I am getting an error that **TypeError: this.props.changeUser is not a function**

Please help me.

Comment: Are you actually defining FirstPage two times in your code? It seems to work here. https://codesandbox.io/s/eager-feistel-6nh6m?file=/src/App.js

Answer (score 0):

try to avoid using a lambda expression within you class component. Just create a simple member function:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import Login from './Login';

class Firstpage extends Component {
    constructor(props){
        super(props);
        this.state=
        {
            user:null
        }
        this.changeUser = this.changeUser.bind(this)
    }
    changeUser(x) // Try to declare this as member function
    {
     console.log(x)
    }
    render() {
        return (
            <div>
               <Login changeUser ={this.changeUser}/>
            </div>
        );
    }
}

export default Firstpage
```

Answer (score -1):

You are making a mistake here while binding , inside constructor

```
//WRONG
this.onNameChange = this.onNameChange.bind(this);
this.onHandleClick = this.onHandleClick.bind(this);

//RIGHT
this.onNameChange = onNameChange.bind(this);
this.onHandleClick = onHandleClick.bind(this);
```

CODE:

```
constructor(props){
        super(props);
        this.state ={
            user : null
        }
        this.onNameChange = onNameChange.bind(this);
        this.onHandleClick = onHandleClick.bind(this);
    }
```

Comment: When i am doing this , it is show error. That is " onNameChange' is not defined   no-undef " and same for other.